# PVlib: Temperature coefficients

Tags: pvlib

I'm modeling a module not found in the databases, so the data I got on the module is from the datasheet.

What is the recommended way of doing this?

The temperature coefficients in the datasheet is given with delta tempearature percentage gain.

in pvlib it's delta temperature * temperature coeficient.

If I understand this correctly I would use an exponential function to calculate the short circuit current given a temperature like so:

Isc * (1 + a_isc^(temperature - referance temperature))

while the way pvlib does it is linear? %/C vs. A/C

Anyway, how to give the best number to pvlib?

Edit: link to datasheet
https://www.jasolar.com.cn/uploadfile/2020/1128/20201128025603510.pdf

Edit2: Example conversion

From datasheet:
Isc = 11.58A
a_Isc = 0.044%/C
(STC values)

conversion:
a_Isc / 100 * 11.58 = 0,0051 A/C

Comment: Are you able to link the datasheet in question?  The difference between %/C and A/C is not whether you multiply or exponentiate but just whether the coefficient is normalized by the STC value or not.

Comment: Edited the question to include a link to the datasheet. So for this module the coefficients is normalized for the STC value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isc * (1 + a_isc^(temperature - referance temperature))

Maybe exponential-style temperature coefficients like that exist, but I've never seen one in PV.  This particular equation doesn't make much sense anyway -- when `temperature == reference temperature`, it should return `Isc` right?  But this equation would return `2*Isc`.

Anyway, to give these coefficients to pvlib, checking the units is the main thing.  Temperature coefficients can be "raw" and have units A/°C, V/°C, or W/°C, or they can be normalized by their STC values and have units %/°C or 1/°C.  The values in that datasheet are normalized (values in %/°C, convert to 1/°C by dividing by 100).  Coefficients in 1/°C can be converted to non-normalized units by multiplying by the corresponding STC value.

It's a shame that pvlib is not consistent in what units it wants; some pvlib functions want the coefficients to be normalized and some don't.  You have to check the documentation of the function you're using to see what units it wants.  For example the [documentation](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.pvsystem.calcparams_cec.html) for `pvlib.pvsystem.calcparams_cec` says:

```
alpha_sc (float) – The short-circuit current temperature coefficient
of the module in units of A/C.
```

And `pvlib.pvsystem.pvwatts_dc` ([docs](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.pvsystem.pvwatts_dc.html)):

```
gamma_pdc (numeric) – The temperature coefficient of power.
Typically -0.002 to -0.005 per degree C. [1/C]
```

Comment: Yes, that formula does only work when having a non zero difference. It's used in economics to account for interest and interest on interest. But I thought that the %/C implies % gain per degree? which would make it exponential in nature. But it seems that I am over-complicating things here. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @lowz I think the point of confusion is that the `%` in `%/°C` is a percentage of the fixed STC value whereas a financial % interest is a percent of last month's value (which changes over time) rather than a % of the original principal (which never changes).  Think simple interest, not compound interest.